# Headset Sound not Working

Tags: sound, headphones, headset

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 on a 64 bit Dell Machine. My speakers are working fine, but my headphone jack just isn't making any sound. I am dual-booting with Windows 7 using Grub as the boot-loader. The sound is working fine in Windows 7 for both headset and speakers.

I have a 7.1 Surround Sound Headset and 2 output jacks. Neither of these 2 jacks seem to work in Ubuntu. The speakers mute like they are supposed to, but there is no sound trough the headset.

Comment: Have you tried to look at Sound Settings and seeing which output device is selected? Try clicking the device you want even if it is already selected.

Comment: @Umang The headset was selected, but when I hit test sound and then click on the little test buttons top right and left, I hear nothing.